# MVC 3 Membership and Authorization 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am developing an MVC3 application and I have gotten to the point where I need to start securing out different areas of the intranet site to particular users.

The site is being used on the intranet and uses windows authentication for login.

Within the database I have a users table which contains numerous fields that determines the users role.  This is maintained in the admin area of the site.

Certain users will have the ability to access the admin area, some users will only have the ability to read certain areas of the site but not contribute, etc etc.  There are some complicated business rules.

I am looking for how to secure out different areas.  I have read a good few articles around using the authorize attribute on controllers for particular groups, this doesn't seem to be a good fit as I understand it I would have to control what users are in what groups from within the configuration of the application whereas the admin users of the application should be ones controlling this via the application itself.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mainly concerned about managing users, ASP.NET does a great job of this with their built-in Web Application Administration Tool. On the top-right of the Solution Explorer, to the right of the refresh button, is a hammer-and -earth tool that you can click on. It allows you to manage users and roles, and from there you can assign the users to roles. Perhaps your admins can use this.

This tells you how:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

As far as having to put authorize attributes on the controllers/methods, I don't see any way around that. Let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assign users to roles and use `AuthorizeAttribute`.